# LinQ Group By and Order By

Tags: linq

List list => Contents:

ID  Counter

---

1   34

5   34

3   55

2   45

4   33

3   123

1   4

5   12

5   133

2   33

I want to group by Id. And I want to pick the big one out of every group and throw it in a new list of the same type.

This is the last version of the list:
ID  Counter

---

1   34

2   45

3   123

4   33

5   133

Comment: And your question/problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Group like this:

```
var groupedData = from item in list
                  orderby item.id
                  group item by item.id into idGroup
                  select new { Id = idGroup.Key, MaxCounter = idGroup.Max(i => i.counter) };
```